# convert this linq expression with loop(s)

Tags: c#, linq, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to debug code that a fellow developer wrote and LINQ expressions are making the task painful.  I don't know how to debug around complicated LINQ expressions, so can anyone tell me what the equivalent code is without them?

```
instanceIdList.AddRange(
  strname.Instances
    .Where(z => instancehealthList.Find(y => y.InstanceId == z.InstanceId 
                                          && y.State == "InService") != null)
    .Select(x => x.InstanceId)
    .ToList()
  .Select(instanceid => new ServerObj(servertype, instanceid))
);
```

Also is this well written?  In general is this sort of LINQ encouraged or frowned upon?

Comment: I would break it down into a couple lines to make it easier to read and debug, but there is nothing "wrong" with it.

Comment: Whether `from x in collection .... select x` or `collecton.Select()`--both are LINQ so I'm not sure what you mean by the "equivalent code". are we talking in terms of straight SQL?

Comment: I guess I'm not really sure how to debug after each iteration.

Comment: @BradChristie For Loops would suit me better

Comment: I would put a breakpoint inside the constructor of `ServerObj` and start there, you also if this is not Linq2Entities you could put the Where clause inside a `{ ... }` section to let you put breakpoints inside that too.

Comment: It greatly depends on which type of LINQ you're talking about: to objects, to SQL, to Entities? And what is this `Find` method? As a linq to _any_ SQL provider this looks a bit clumsy at best.

Comment: `Find` is a method on `List<T>` that predates LINQ. To be more LINQ-y that part could be rewritten as `.Where(z => instanceHealthList.Any(y => y.InstanceId == z.InstanceId && y.State == "InService"))`

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Yes, thanks, I see now. I wanted to know if it wasn't the DbSet method, but that's got a different signature.

Comment: In fact, this whole thing is better written as `strname.Instances.Where(z => instanceHealthList.Any(y => y.InstanceId == z.InstanceId && y.State == "InService")).Select(z => new ServerObj(servertype, z.instanceid))` The projection into just `InstanceId` and the immediate `ToList` aren't necessary.

Comment: @user2081737 BTW you can also set breakpoints _in_ lambda expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refactoring the query using loops would look something like this:

```
var serverObjList = new List<ServerObj>();
foreach (var inst in strname.Instances)
{
    foreach (var health in instancehealthList)
    {
        if (inst.InstanceID == health.InstanceID && health.State == "InService") 
        {
            serverObjList.Add(new ServerObj(servertype, health.InstanceID));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than rewrite it to a series of `foreach` loops, you could eagerly-execute the expression after each operation, allowing you to inspect the data-set at intermediate steps, like so:

```
List<var> soFar = strname.Instances.Where(z => instancehealthList.Find(y => y.InstanceId == z.InstanceId && y.State == "InService") != null).ToList();

List<Int64> soFar2 = soFar.Select( x => x.InstanceId ).ToList();

List<ServerObj> soFar3 = soFar2.Select( instanceId => new ServerObj(servertype, instanceid) ).ToList();

instanceIdList.AddRange( soFar3 );
```

Of course, I feel this Linq isn't well-written.